# I will be using a business visa 90 days in Russia, Have anyone faced problems by custom or police about "what kind of business I'm doing?"

Tags: visas, russia, business-travel

I will soon receive a buiness visa after one month duration is 3 months.
I might sound funny, but will I get into a trouble if im not a buiness man?? I dont even have work, but I mean I have saved my money. But like buiness visa require me to fill in some working information , so I randomly fill in some working information that i have worked before. Will this be a problem??

Have any one also traveled in Russia over 30 days as buiness visa holder? If so please I really hope I can hear from you , I have no one to ask in Taiwan.

Is there some regions that business visa holder can't enter? Because I know there are a lot of region that tourist visa holder can not enter, but I mean I'm a business holder.

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear. What is the purpose of your visit to Russia? It sounds as if you lied on the application - what exactly did you state and how does that differ from your true circumstances? Did you use an agent to submit your visa application?

Answer (score 5):

You are in risk of not being admitted to country if you lied on the application. Customs and immigration officers will almost always ask why are you entering the country, what do you do there and when do you plan to leave.

If they are suspicious, then they will question further. Based on that you are in risk of refusing entry and sending back. You should be declaring the same for all visa applications and have to truthfully explain what happened.

In short, its a huge risk to get visa under false pretenses and seeking entry.

Comment: This advice is good, but just a note regarding ”immigration officers will almost always ask why are you entering the country, what do you do there and when do you plan to leave”: that’s true in many places, but across the four times I’ve entered Russia in the last 14 months, I’ve been asked a total of zero questions.

Comment: YMMV, and I'm not a frequent visitor to Russia, but I've never been asked *anything* on entry.  Interrogation seems to reserved for visa applicants.

Comment: @anish sheela, thank you for your words, but like a lot of people being asked zero questions, so i think ill keep asking more peoples advices thank you;))

Comment: @ChrisH   thank you man , so you mean you travel in russia as a tourist while holding busines visa, but custom and police ask you zero question??  i just wanna thank you again chris, thank you:))

Comment: @ChrisH   thank you man , so you mean you travel in russia as a tourist while holding busines visa, but custom and police ask you zero question??  i just wanna thank you again chris, thank you:))

Comment: There is a probability they won't ask anything as there is a probability they will ask a ton of questions...

Answer (score 3):

On business visa you suppose to have business meeting or something for your company or as freelance to do in Russia, so if they ask you why you are there you can simply say the reason, show your meetings or what you suppose to do there.

Custom duty is like russian roulette, may they ask you questions may nothing, depend by your nationality and by luck. Or may they don't speak any english and they let you go.

Comment: I think that immigration at international airport would speak at least some English. As for OP, I think he should do some research to find some event on those dates, claim he wishes to attend - if questioned. Ideally, actually show up there :)

Comment: By land most of the time no, I crossed Russia from Mongolia, China and Kazakhstan and they dont' speak any English. At Airport I hope somebody speak at least basic English, but it's Russia.
Last time I try to speak English but no way, I just use my bad work in progress Russian.

Comment: When entering by land, business visa may cause a lot of extra questioning anyway, especially for an islander.

Comment: @Sarah may i ask you did you travel russia while holding business visa?? did custom ask you questions about business visa?? becasue im scared that they will ask me questions , because im a tourist

Answer (score 2):

So you lied in your application and you are asking if this might cause problems? The answer to that is YES